# Yes/No attributes in logical database design

Tags: erd

I have an assignment where I have to design a logical model using SQL developer.

I am converting a conceptual model to a logical model. And I Have  a relation NURSE that has "nurse_id" and "certification". The certification attribute has yes/no values.

**My question is:**
Should I move the yes/no attribute to a new relation? or is it okay to keep it in the same NURSE relation. What is the best practise.

and is the suitable data type for that attribute (CHAR)?

Thank you,

Comment: I noticed that you have asked a few questions on StackOverflow but not accepted answers that people have given you. Is there a reason why? I'd recommend that you mark an answer as accepted to put closure to your question - not only for this question but previous questions you've asked on StackOverflow also.

Comment: I didn't know about this feature. I will make sure to do that from now on. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it in the NURSE relation as it would be easy to query how many nurses have certification and how many don't, and which nurses have certification.

You can use either CHAR(1) and type in Y or N. You can use a BIT datatype if database supports it. You can use a Boolean if database supports it. Since all major databases will have a CHAR(1), I'd just keep it CHAR(1)

Answer (score 0):

Because the certification only has yes/no values, I would recommend keeping them in the same table as a one to one mapping.  If one nurse could get several certifications, then another table would be useful as a many to one or one to many mapping.

As for the data type, CHAR is fine.  If you want to save space you can also use BOOLEAN, then parse this as yes/no in the application.